# Streaming desktop from windows VPS stops on Minimise of Client window

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I am streaming to youtube via a Windows 2012 R2 desktop server VPS.
Everything is fine and dandy until i minimise my remote desktop window on my side or close it then the stream stops and my vps goes "black" i then maximise the remote desktop client or log back in and everything continues to work. I have gone into power and turned monitor shutdown to never, what are my other options? I would like to have the windows server configured so the "desktop" continues to run even after i log out from the remote desktop client. Something like "screen" for windows desktops ?

The user is not loggin out everything is remaining where i was its just the GUI is kinda disappearing on close of Remote desktop client or miminize of it.